# Why is Implicit Runge-Kutta implicit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

Why is Implicit Runge-Kutta implicit? Moreover there is adaptive Runge-Kutta, etc. All of them them can solve IVP problem (implicit differential equation). What the real reason why this particular method is implicit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely refer with IVP to **I**nitial **V**alue **P**roblems?

"Implicit" in general means that to get to the desired value you have to solve a , in general non-linear, system of equations instead of just evaluating a function, which would give you an explicit method to get at the desired value.